# How do I pass every value in an HashSet Collection?

Tags: c#, forms, hashset

```
foreach (var item in HashSet<T>)
{

}
```

What should be the var?

Comment: That doesn't compile. What is your question anyway?

Comment: of course it does not compile.... How do I go through every value in an HashSet Collection? I want to check what the HashSet contains..

Comment: See [HashSet<T>.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` ([implicitly typed variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)) will be exactly the type you have defined in `T` when you declared your `HashSet`.

So for example, if you declared it `HashSet<int>`, `var` will be of type `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't compile, you should use something like:

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(); //create a HashSet of integers

//populate hashSet

foreach(var value in hashSet){ //where var is of type int
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

var is T (30 characters) (30 characters) (30 characters) (30 characters)

Answer (score 1):

var is T, float the mouse over `var` and VS will tell you the type.